# Rails: Error cause user to restart window. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, restart

I am running a new web application in Rails, running on Heroku. I am getting complaints from my users that this calculation does not work: http:// www. countcalculate .com/body/sober-after-alcohol-consumption

Appearantly the users get a message that they need to restart the window (?) and that it doesn't work at all. I have not been able to get better explanations than that (one way communication from the users). I don't really know what to look for in the logs either.

1. What would cause this kind of error message?
2. Could it be related to the time out that I have set (12 seconds)?
3. Is it related to Heroku or Rails you think?

Can you replicate the error or give me advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors like that can only come from Javascript - there are 6 errors if you view the javascript console.

Comment: I can't really verify this but it seems likely to be the answer.